# number of MPI processes can exceed number of logical processors on a node

Tags: mpi, intel

I have a simple MPI code that print out the rank of process, compiled and linked with Intel compiler and MPI library.
Then I ran it on the master node of a cluster interactively: mpiexec -n 50 ./a.out
The node only have 12 cores and 24 logical processors (hyperthreading?).
But I can ran it with 50 and even more processes. 
What's the reason?

Comment: running MPI programs on the master node of a shared cluster is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The processes can run on the same core, the operating system schedule the process, given some amount of CPU time to each one.

In MPI, using more processes than cores is called 'oversubscribing'.For more information see the following URL: http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running#oversubscribing